# Change color of all elements on any svg file

Tags: c#, xml, svg

I can easily add a fill on the element (`<path fill="#FF0000">`), but my problem is, that it is not always a path element, it can also be `<rect>`, `<ellipse>` and so on.

but what if i want to change the color of all the elements in the svg file? no matter what type it is?

My solutions:

- Find all elements that support the fill attribute, and then loop through them.
- Just to put a fill tag on everything, not matter what tag, but not all tags support it, and wont that cause problems?

I don't like any of these solutions... The first is not dynamic, and the other is not dynamic is dirty¨

Is there something smarter i can do here? can i define a global color or something? Or does [svg.codeplex](http://svg.codeplex.com/) have some functionality that i can use (which i can't find)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use css to set the colours. If you remove the fill styles from the elements themselves then you can just add

```
<style type="text/css">
  <![CDATA[
    * {
      fill: #FF0000;
    }
  ]]>
</style>
```

or alternatively in an external stylesheet and everything that accepts a fill colour will be red. You can manipulate the styles using [document.styleSheets[1]](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/stylesheet.shtml)

Comment: Thanks. But the thing is. I need to do it on the server. But doest this css code do the same as my seccond dirty solution?

Comment: So create the style element on the server with whatever fill you want in it.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried XPath?  (using System.Xml.XPath)

```
string newColor = "#123456";
XElement root = XElement.Load(file);
var colors = root.XPathSelectElements("//*[@fill]");
foreach(XElement node in colors)
    node.Attribute("fill").Value = newColor;
```

PS this is an answer to your first bullet.